# What are the side effects of querying the database when authorizing access to resources?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, security, asp.net-web-api

Disclaimer
The question is more conceptual then technology oriented, but for clarity we are developing an **Angular** app based on **.NET MVC** with **WebApi** system.

We are currently implementing the authorization logic using our own `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Permissions are stored in the database as they are dynamic, and not role oriented.
With the current design, we consult the database each time the user wants to access a secure page / API.

My guess is that performance wise it would be better to get all permissions once the user logs-in, and read them from memory.
However, in case someone changes the user permissions while the user is working, new permissions won't be reflected.

What is the best practice here?
Access the database on each request "just" to check permissions?
Any other side-effects or considerations I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

One mitigation to the cached permissions risk could be forced logout functionality - when an admin changes permissions of a user, he could terminate that user's session (or it could be automatically terminated if any permissions are revoked). Of course depending on how the application is used and by whom, this may or may not be a good mitigation.

Also as memory in this case is technically a cache, you can implement some kind of a cache invalidation logic, in the simplest case you can store in memory the timestamp of when authorization rights were read from the database and after a set time reread them. Obviously this would make some unfortunate requests slower than the others, which (and the residual risk of permission changes not being effective at once) again may or may not be acceptable in your case.

You can also choose to implement full blown caching with some kind of a cache solution, but it's getting more difficult as you will have to care about the integrity of cached permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that best practice is subjective, so I won't even go there. Though in my opinion, getting as much from the database up-front would be optimal.

Since permissions can change while a user is logged in, you can cache all their permissions up-front and use the [SqlCacheDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) to keep the cache in sync with the permissions in the database.